# Achieving a plot similar to a RegionPlot with discrete data

Tags: plotting

I have the following data in the format of {x1,y1,z1}:

```
{{0.05, 0, 2.09412}, {0.1, 0, 2.00505}, {0.15, 0, 1.8692}, {0.2, 0, 
  1.70208}, {0.25, 0, 1.51965}, {0.3, 0, 1.33654}, {0.35, 0, 
  1.16343}, {0.4, 0, 1.01005}, {0.45, 0, 0.883653}, {0.5, 0, 
  0.792333}, {0.6, 0, 0.794668}, {0.65, 0, 1.08459}, {0, -10, 
  2.11716}, {0.05, -10, 2.08704}, {0.1, -10, 2.00062}, {0.15, -10, 
  1.5764}, {0.2, -10, 1.69942}, {0.25, -10, 1.1256}, {0.3, -10, 
  0.915311}, {0.35, -10, 0.724784}, {0.4, -10, 0.557347}, {0.45, -10, 
  0.414329}, {0.5, -10, 0.295847}, {0.55, -10, 0.201322}, {0.6, -10, 
  0.129954}, {0.65, -10, 0.0809156}, {0.7, -10, 
  0.0535506}, {0.75, -10, 0.0474673}, {0, -20, 2.12459}, {0.05, -20, 
  2.01208}, {0.1, -20, 1.84956}, {0.15, -20, 1.81342}, {0.2, -20, 
  1.64175}, {0.25, -20, 1.45434}, {0.3, -20, 1.26322}, {0.35, -20, 
  1.07861}, {0.45, -20, 0.544381}, {0.5, -20, 0.625104}, {0.55, -20, 
  0.335852}, {0.6, -20, 0.265945}, {0.65, -20, 0.218091}, {0.7, -20, 
  0.330485}, {0.75, -20, 0.186575}, {0, -30, 2.12495}, {0.05, -30, 
  2.04312}, {0.1, -30, 1.95586}, {0.15, -30, 1.81408}, {0.2, -30, 
  1.6472}, {0.25, -30, 1.46717}, {0.3, -30, 1.28524}, {0.35, -30, 
  1.11062}, {0.4, -30, 0.949941}, {0.45, -30, 0.807552}, {0.5, -30, 
  0.685852}, {0.55, -30, 0.586033}, {0.6, -30, 0.508438}, {0.65, -30, 
  0.452949}, {0.7, -30, 0.419327}, {0.75, -30, 0.40741}, {0, -40, 
  2.12564}, {0.05, -40, 2.07402}, {0.1, -40, 1.97611}, {0.15, -40, 
  1.80464}, {0.2, -40, 1.68348}, {0.25, -40, 1.51231}, {0.4, -40, 
  1.02099}, {0.45, -40, 0.886038}, {0.5, -40, 0.771047}, {0.55, -40, 
  0.677185}, {0.6, -40, 0.604868}, {0.65, -40, 0.554097}, {0.75, -40, 
  0.51663}, {0, -50, 2.12519}, {0.1, -50, 2.00847}, {0.15, -50, 
  1.88592}, {0.25, -50, 1.57604}, {0.3, -50, 1.41193}, {0.35, -50, 
  1.20883}, {0.4, -50, 1.06172}, {0.45, -50, 0.979901}, {0.5, -50, 
  0.870339}, {0.55, -50, 0.781138}, {0.6, -50, 0.712876}, {0.65, -50, 
  0.665729}, {0.7, -50, 0.639627}, {0.75, -50, 0.603863}, {0, -60, 
  2.12294}, {0.05, -60, 2.11458}, {0.1, -60, 2.06337}, {0.15, -60, 
  1.9396}, {0.2, -60, 1.80301}, {0.25, -60, 1.65146}, {0.3, -60, 
  1.49609}, {0.35, -60, 1.34578}, {0.4, -60, 1.20679}, {0.45, -60, 
  1.08345}, {0.5, -60, 0.978466}, {0.55, -60, 0.893153}, {0.6, -60, 
  0.828311}, {0.65, -60, 0.766473}, {0.75, -60, 0.757909}, {0, -70, 
  2.1163}, {0.1, -70, 2.09201}, {0.15, -70, 1.99933}, {0.25, -70, 
  1.73465}, {0.3, -70, 1.58807}, {0.35, -70, 1.44493}, {0.4, -70, 
  1.31189}, {0.45, -70, 1.19181}, {0.5, -70, 1.09252}, {0.55, -70, 
  1.01063}, {0.65, -70, 0.906969}, {0.7, -70, 0.885735}, {0.75, -70, 
  0.885036}, {0, -80, 2.11109}, {0.05, -80, 2.16128}, {0.1, -80, 
  2.13834}, {0.15, -80, 2.06322}, {0.2, -80, 1.95322}, {0.25, -80, 
  1.82325}, {0.3, -80, 1.68531}, {0.35, -80, 1.54924}, {0.4, -80, 
  1.4219}, {0.45, -80, 1.30806}, {0.5, -80, 1.2108}, {0.55, -80, 
  1.13193}, {0.6, -80, 1.07251}, {0.65, -80, 1.03302}, {0.7, -80, 
  1.01374}, {0.75, -80, 1.01484}, {0, -90, 2.1012}, {0.1, -90, 
  2.18573}, {0.15, -90, 2.12946}, {0.2, -90, 2.03395}, {0.25, -90, 
  1.91529}, {0.3, -90, 1.78634}, {0.35, -90, 1.65728}, {0.4, -90, 
  1.53539}, {0.45, -90, 1.44954}, {0.5, -90, 1.33206}, {0.55, -90, 
  1.256}, {0.6, -90, 1.19888}, {0.65, -90, 1.16138}, {0.7, -90, 
  1.1439}, {0.75, -90, 1.14658}, {0, -100, 2.08892}, {0.05, -100, 
  2.21053}, {0.1, -100, 2.23328}, {0.15, -100, 2.19699}, {0.2, -100, 
  2.11682}, {0.25, -100, 2.0099}, {0.3, -100, 1.93021}, {0.35, -100, 
  1.76802}, {0.55, -100, 1.38212}, {0.6, -100, 1.32714}, {0.65, -100, 
  1.29147}, {0.7, -100, 1.27558}, {0.75, -100, 1.27976}, {0, -110, 
  2.07483}, {0.05, -110, 2.22384}, {0.1, -110, 2.29696}, {0.15, -110, 
  2.26525}, {0.2, -110, 2.20105}, {0.25, -110, 2.10633}, {0.3, -110, 
  1.99567}, {0.35, -110, 1.88055}, {0.4, -110, 1.76944}, {0.45, -110, 
  1.70653}, {0.5, -110, 1.58073}, {0.55, -110, 1.50977}, {0.6, -110, 
  1.45684}, {0.65, -110, 1.4229}, {0.7, -110, 1.40855}, {0.75, -110, 
  1.41406}, {0, -120, 2.05932}, {0.05, -120, 2.24053}, {0.1, -120, 
  2.32622}, {0.15, -120, 2.33349}, {0.2, -120, 2.28603}, {0.25, -120, 
  2.20381}, {0.3, -120, 2.15022}, {0.4, -120, 1.88875}, {0.45, -120, 
  1.7915}, {0.5, -120, 1.70719}, {0.55, -120, 1.63861}, {0.6, -120, 
  1.58767}, {0.7, -120, 1.54239}, {0.75, -120, 1.54925}, {0, -130, 
  2.04175}, {0.05, -130, 2.25467}, {0.1, -130, 2.37059}, {0.15, -130, 
  2.4013}, {0.25, -130, 2.30201}, {0.3, -130, 2.2105}, {0.35, -130, 
  2.10961}, {0.4, -130, 2.0092}, {0.45, -130, 1.9159}, {0.5, -130, 
  1.83461}, {0.55, -130, 1.7684}, {0.6, -130, 1.71929}, {0.65, -130, 
  1.68857}, {0.7, -130, 1.67701}, {0.75, -130, 1.68508}, {0, -140, 
  2.02214}, {0.05, -140, 2.26615}, {0.1, -140, 2.41313}, {0.15, -140, 
  2.46827}, {0.2, -140, 2.45649}, {0.25, -140, 2.40065}, {0.3, -140, 
  2.31894}, {0.4, -140, 2.13038}, {0.45, -140, 2.04116}, {0.5, -140, 
  1.96286}, {0.55, -140, 1.8989}, {0.6, -140, 1.85167}, {0.65, -140, 
  1.82245}, {0.7, -140, 1.81224}, {0.75, -140, 1.8215}, {0, -150, 
  2.00046}, {0.05, -150, 2.27555}, {0.1, -150, 2.45351}, {0.15, -150, 
  2.53417}, {0.25, -150, 2.49932}, {0.3, -150, 2.42779}, {0.35, -150, 
  2.39361}, {0.4, -150, 2.25218}, {0.45, -150, 2.16694}, {0.5, -150, 
  2.09159}, {0.55, -150, 2.03005}, {0.6, -150, 1.98459}, {0.65, -150, 
  1.95688}, {0.7, -150, 1.94792}, {0.75, -150, 1.95841}, {0, -160, 
  1.97679}, {0.05, -160, 2.28305}, {0.1, -160, 2.49248}, {0.15, -160, 
  2.59871}, {0.2, -160, 2.62551}, {0.25, -160, 2.59793}, {0.3, -160, 
  2.53685}, {0.35, -160, 2.45838}, {0.4, -160, 2.37431}, {0.5, -160, 
  2.2209}, {0.55, -160, 2.16152}, {0.6, -160, 2.1179}, {0.65, -160, 
  2.09163}, {0.7, -160, 2.08399}, {0, -170, 1.95107}, {0.05, -170, 
  2.28874}, {0.1, -170, 2.52693}, {0.15, -170, 2.66171}, {0.2, -170, 
  2.70897}, {0.25, -170, 2.69625}, {0.3, -170, 2.64592}, {0.35, -170, 
  2.57521}, {0.4, -170, 2.49675}, {0.45, -170, 2.41973}, {0.5, -170, 
  2.35045}, {0.55, -170, 2.29341}, {0.65, -170, 2.22678}, {0.7, -170, 
  2.22043}, {0.75, -170, 2.23318}, {0, -180, 1.92335}, {0.05, -180, 
  2.29265}, {0.1, -180, 2.55992}, {0.15, -180, 2.72297}, {0.2, -180, 
  2.7915}, {0.25, -180, 2.79413}, {0.3, -180, 2.75487}, {0.35, -180, 
  2.69217}, {0.4, -180, 2.61944}, {0.45, -180, 2.54656}, {0.5, -180, 
  2.4804}, {0.55, -180, 2.47704}, {0.6, -180, 2.38554}, {0.65, -180, 
  2.3622}, {0.75, -180, 2.37093}, {0, -190, 1.89362}, {0.05, -190, 
  2.29474}, {0.15, -190, 2.78236}, {0.25, -190, 2.89155}, {0.3, -190, 
  2.86372}, {0.35, -190, 2.80908}, {0.4, -190, 2.74222}, {0.5, -190, 
  2.61049}, {0.55, -190, 2.55803}, {0.65, -190, 2.49787}, {0.7, -190, 
  2.49395}, {0.75, -190, 2.55036}}
```

I would like to plot a density plot with 2 distinct colours, one for the region with $z<2.2$, and one for the region with $z>2.2$.

Something like this, where the green region refers to points with values greater than 2.2. and the red region refers to points with values smaller than 2.2

[image]

Is it possible to achieve a similar effect with discrete points?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### ListContourPlot

```
ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> {2.2},
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 ContourShading -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

#### Interpolation + ContourPlot

```
iF = Interpolation[{{#, #2}, #3} & @@@ data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

ContourPlot[iF[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -200, 0}, 
 Contours -> {2.2}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 ContourShading -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

#### Interpolation + RegionPlot

```
RegionPlot[{iF[x, y] <= 2.2, iF[x, y] >= 2.2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -200, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: @bobthelegend, my pleasure.